# Working with multiple terminals one of which is mission critical?

Tags: gnome-terminal

So I have a mission critical though not-at-all resource intensive node.js program continuously running 24/7 in one terminal on an Ubuntu 18 virtualbox, and I need to use one or two additional terminals for dev work and research. Eventually I will have the first program on a cloud VPS or second machine, but for now it is on my primary workstation.

I am a novice at this, so please forgive my asking, but:

1. Are the multiple terminals completely sandboxed?
2. If I am running a CPU/Memory intensive operation on a second terminal, will it an any way interfere with the first terminal, aside from using overall resources?
3. Is there a good way to prioritize Network, CPU, and Memory resources for the mission critical terminal?

Comment: I'd suggest you use `screen` and have your program run in a `screen` session, so you shouldn't need one terminal constantly open. As for resources, you might consider tuning niceness value https://askubuntu.com/q/48708/295286  so that CPU gives preference to that particular program

Answer (score 1):

"Terminals" themselves are not the `node` process that's actually doing the work. The output you see on the terminal you see are merely a representation of the `stdin` and `stdout` of the process.

The process itself will be called `node` and it's functioning is not directly linked to the terminal except that when the terminal is closed ( i.e `SIGHUP` is sent to the process since it's the child of the terminal ), the process is shut down, since the terminal created the process by forking itself and replacing its contents with your `node` application. This can be circumvented by adding an `&` to the end of the command (which makes it ignore `SIGHUP`) or running your command inside a `screen` or `tmux` session (recommended since you can easily connect back)

Hence to answer your questions

1. Since terminals don't really "contain" your process, there isn't really any isolation between them. If any process has root access, it can mess with any other process
2. This all depends on the `nice`ness value of the process in question since if more overall CPU time is granted to a process with a lesser `nice` value, and hence can potentially slow down any other process with a higher `nice` value if the system is being pushed to the limit
3. `nice` allows you to set the 'niceness' of a process, the lower the niceness, the more the priority. As for network you can use `trickle` to shape the bandwidth

In any case running anything mission critical on a system that's also used for research/dev work is not very optimal and should be avoided whenever it's possible