# Distribute workload among different CPUs

Tags: cpu, cpu-load, intel-cpu

On my Ubuntu 16.04, I am running a program that is relatively expensive in terms of CPU usage. It takes quite much time to finish, and other tasks (like browsing the web) get slower as a consequence. I was looking for a way to improve the computing power, if possible and at the same time to know better what is happening in my laptop.

By this, I found that, if I ask `top`, the program I am running shows a CPU usage of 100%, while when I open the `System monitor` the CPU usage is only at ~25% in the `Processes` tab. In addition, the `Resources` tab in System monitor shows 4 CPUs, whose usage changes from ~5 to ~100% for each one:

[image: CPUs usage]

The outcome of `lscpu` is:

```
@C:~$ lscpu
Architecture:          x86_64
CPU op-mode(s):        32-bit, 64-bit
Byte Order:            Little Endian
CPU(s):                4
On-line CPU(s) list:   0-3
Thread(s) per core:    2
Core(s) per socket:    2
Socket(s):             1
NUMA node(s):          1
Vendor ID:             GenuineIntel
CPU family:            6
Model:                 142
Model name:            Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-7200U CPU @2.50GHz
Stepping:              9
CPU MHz:               3099.937
CPU max MHz:           3100,0000
CPU min MHz:           400,0000
BogoMIPS:              5423.81
Virtualization:        VT-x
L1d cache:             32K
L1i cache:             32K
L2 cache:              256K
L3 cache:              3072K
NUMA node0 CPU(s):     0-3
```

Is there anything I can do to improve the situation, such as dilute the work among the 4 CPUs? Usinge [`nice`](https://askubuntu.com/questions/48708/change-niceness-priority-of-a-running-process) does not seem a solution to my situation.

I know this may be a general question that depends on the type of program I am running (let's say it is a `Python` script), but I am trying here to get general knowledge.

Comment: Instead of "a program" it would be better to tell us the real program name that is taking 100% CPU.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there anything I can do to improve the situation, such as dilute the work among the 4 CPUs? Usinge nice does not seem a solution to my situation.

In short: no. The program is single threaded.

Top can show cpu use in two ways: saturation per CPU, or share of total. If you have a four core system, top may show Irix mode:

> Also for multi-processor environments, if Irix  mode  is  Off,  top will  operate  in  Solaris  mode  where  a task's cpu usage will be divided by the total number of CPUs.  You toggle Irix/Solaris modes with the `I' interactive command.

You can toggle this by pressing I in top. As you have four CPU cores, the use is divided by four, and you will show 25%. If you turn on Irix mode, it will show 100%.

Your application is single threaded. It executes a sequential thread, on one CPU core. If you have the source code, you *can* change this. It's usually not a trivial task however, and depending on task it may not be possible.

Linux has a scheduler which will distribute running threads to different CPUs/cores.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Can you tell how you _know_ that the program is single threaded? Also, what is the "scheduler" you are mentioning at the end of your answer?

Comment: You can know in three ways: read the source, read the documentation, or observe it. The fact that it fully utilize one core is a solid indication. Regarding scheduler, this is the system responsible for distributing threads to available CPUs.

Comment: Great. So the scheduler is not like an app that the user can manage, but rather an automatic process which I can't (or hardly can, if I was a pro) access.

Comment: You can manage it to a certain extent. The Linux kernel has different schedulers, but they won't change how a single threaded program work. They may for instance favor response time over throughput. This generally depends on the workload the computer is running.[Wikipedia has an entry on Schedulers.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scheduling_(computing))

Answer (score 1):

### 100% vs 25% CPU usage

According to `lscpu`, you have four cores in your CPU:

```
On-line CPU(s) list:   0-3
```

`top` uses 100% per core, so if you have a four-core processor, that's 400%. You're using one core up completely, so that's 100% out of the 400%. The system monitor uses 100% for everything (or perhaps per actual CPU, I'm not sure). One core is a quarter of the four cores available, so it shows up as 25% usage in the system monitor.

### Significant slowdown with one core used

If the system is slowing down a bit, it's probably just the CPU usage, and you can't do much about that other than raising the niceness value of the workload's processes.

If it's slowing down to a lot less than three-quarters speed, it's probably using a lot of I/O so that other applications can't do I/O very quickly, either using files or the network or swapping if there isn't enough RAM in the system, which are all shown in the system monitor application. File usage and swapping are also shown with `sudo iotop`.

### Changing the task's priority

You can use `nice` with a high value like 15 to make the task give way to other tasks that need the CPU:

```
nice -n 15 the-program its-arguments
```

### Slowing the task down

You can try both `nice`ing the program to a high value like 15 and using the `cpulimit` program (in the `cpulimit` APT package) to reduce the CPU usage while it's allowed to run.

An example slowing the `the-program its-arguments` down to 60% CPU usage and using a niceness value of 15:

```
cpulimit -q -z -l 60 -- nice -n 15 the-program its-arguments
```

### Using multiple cores

There are a few ways to proceed as far as splitting up the workload to use more cores. This is probably not what you want to do if you're trying to do other things on the computer, since it can use up **even more** processing power to do the tasks faster.

One is to run the process four times each with one quarter of the workload, if there's some way to specify the workload when running it. One possibility useful in some circumstances is using `xargs -n ## -P 4 command` to process `##` items at a time on each core using 4 cores.

Another is to rewrite the application to use four or so threads instead of just one. If there's a lot of I/O waiting in your application or something like that, you can potentially increase it far above four threads.

There are other possibilities as well.

### Combining using multiple cores with slowing the task down and setting the niceness value

You can combine using multiple cores with slowing the task down or changing the task's priority. This will allow you to have the task finish more quickly but to get out of the way of other processes.